# finding the mean of two values in the same dictionary

Tags: python, csv, mean

I have a csv file that contains this information

```
grade,low,high
S235,360,510
S275,370,530
S355,470,630
```

I am wanting to find the difference between high and low but I don't know how to do this. I thought I could do it through numpy (np.mean) but it came up with an error.

this is the code I have written so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv  

csvfile = open('/home/aa408/steel.csv')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

print("%7s %8s %8s" % ("Grade", "Low MPa", "Max MPa") )

total = 0
count = 0

for gradeInfo in csvreader:
    print("%7s %8s %8s" % (gradeInfo["grade"], gradeInfo["low"], 
                           gradeInfo["high"]) )
```

Comment: Why are you calculating mean if you want difference?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I got my words around the wrong way sorry! I have to 1) print the difference between the different grades and 2) print a mean of the tensile difference (across all grades) so that where I got mixed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will calculate the difference between the high and low columns assuming they will only be integers.

```
import csv

with open('/home/aa408/steel.csv') as cf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(cf)
    print(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(int(row['high']) - int(row['low']))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I don't know a lot about python but this was clear to understand and follow through